# Monitor 2 apps on the same machine with VisualVM

Tags: java, eclipse, mule, anypoint-studio, visualvm

I have a Mule project running locally and I need to test it for memory usage. I'm currently trying to use Java VisualVM and I like it so far.

Unfortunately I'm encountering problems when I try to test this app because it is a client app that connects to other APIs and these APIs are running locally. Unfortunately I have no way to run these apps externally and still connect.

The issue here is that, because these APIs are running and using the same JVM, when my memory usage increases, there is no way to know whether my client app is using more memory or if it's one of the APIs.

Is there a way to isolate data from my client app while running my APIs on the same machine? I'm also open to using another tool aside from Visual VM.

Thanks,

--Drew

Comment: Can you not run the apps in different JVMs on the same machine?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that in Mulesoft but I'll look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.